# inotify program in c create extra notifications

Tags: c

while creating a file this program displays as follows when created "untitled document" and after that it renamed to "rr.txt"

```
The file Untitled Document was Created with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
The writtable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file Untitled Document was closed with WD 1
The file Untitled Document was moved from X with WD 1
The file rr.txt was moved to Y with WD 1
The file rr.txt was opened with WD 1
unwrittable file rr.txt was closed with WD 1
```

the program written as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_EVENTS 1024 /*Max. number of events to process at one go*/
#define LEN_NAME 16 /*Assuming that the length of the filename won't exceed 16 bytes*/
#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) ) /*size of one event*/
#define BUF_LEN     ( MAX_EVENTS * ( EVENT_SIZE + LEN_NAME )) /*buffer to store the data of events*/

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int length, i = 0, wd;
    int fd;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    /* Initialize Inotify*/
    fd = inotify_init();
    if ( fd < 0 )
    {
        perror( "Couldn't initialize inotify");
    }

    /* add watch to starting directory */
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, argv[1], IN_ACCESS | IN_MODIFY | IN_ATTRIB | IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE | IN_OPEN | IN_MOVED_FROM | IN_MOVED_TO | IN_DELETE | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE_SELF);

    if (wd == -1)
    {
        printf("Couldn't add watch to %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Watching:: %s\n",argv[1]);
    }

    /* do it forever*/
    while(1)
    {
        i = 0;
        length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );

        if ( length < 0 )
        {
            perror( "read" );
        }

        while ( i < length )
        {
            struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
            if ( event->len )
            {
                if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was created.\n", event->name );
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was Created with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );     
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)                                 
                        printf( "The directory %s was modified.\n", event->name );     
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was modified with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );     
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was deleted.\n", event->name );     
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was deleted with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );     
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_ATTRIB)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The metadata of directory %s was changed.\n", event->name );
                    else
                        printf( "The metadata of file %s was changed with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
                {
                    printf( "The writtable file %s was closed with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
                {
                    printf( "unwrittable file %s was closed with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_OPEN)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was opened.\n", event->name );
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was opened with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was moved from X.\n", event->name );
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was moved from X with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_MOVED_TO)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was moved to Y\n", event->name );
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was moved to Y with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE_SELF)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was deleted.\n", event->name );
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was deleted with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_ACCESS)
                {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was accessed.\n", event->name );
                    else
                        printf( "The file %s was accessed with WD %d\n", event->name, event->wd );
                }

                i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Clean up*/
    inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
    close( fd );

    return 0;
}
```

i didnt open ad close the file. but many times prints it open and close. also prints it moved which i didnt do. plz help me to correct the bug

Comment: If `inotify` reports it, it did happen....

Comment: Probably nothing wrong with your result, but you should align your buffer anyway `char buffer[BUF_LEN] __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(struct inotify_event))));` according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html#EXAMPLE

Comment: Can you describe, where and how you create your file? The detailed handling might be different between shell and UI explorer, between windows and linux and so on.

Comment: i create file on my home of linux. i create as usual by right click with mouse and 'create new folder'

Comment: and you don't think a GUI file manager *might* open/read/etc files in order to display them graphically?